# Satisfiability and Truth in First Order Model Theory

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

In Mendelson's book An Introduction to Mathematical Logic he introduces the use of denumerable sequences in the following section:

[image]

Near the end of this passage he states: "Let $\Sigma$ be the set of all denumerable sequences of elements of D". How do we visual these denumerable sequences? I don't quite understand their purpose here. They're clearly more than an ordered representation of the free variables; are they infinite?

Comment: It's not for any one particular formula. This is a global variable assignment. You have (in the language) a countably infinite set of free variables $(x_1,x_2,\ldots).$ We want to assign each of these variables an element of the domain. Each infinite sequence of domain elements $(s_1,s_2,\ldots)$ corresponds to an assignment where $s_1$ is plugged in for $x_1,$ $s_2$ is plugged in for $x_2,$ etc, wherever those variables occur free in a formula.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So what is the cardinality of $\Sigma$? Is it equal to the cardinality of the domain?

Comment: It's the set of all infinite (length $\omega$) sequences of domain elements. So has cardinality $|D|^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: Okay, but say the domain was {1,2,3}, $\Sigma$ would still be $\mid D\mid^{\aleph _0}$?

Comment: Yes. The number of infinite sequences from $D$ is $|D|^{\aleph_0}.$ That's pretty much the definition of $|D|^{\aleph_0}.$ So it's $0$ if the domain is empty, $1$ if there is one element, and continuum-many if the domain is finite with more than one element or countably infinite (or even anything up to cardinality of continuum).

Comment: So in my example of {1,2,3} it would be 3? Sorry, I feel like there's a disconnect here.

Comment: No, the domain $\{1,2,3\}$ has cardinality $3.$ So the cardinality of $\Sigma$ is $3^{\aleph_0},$ which is equal to $2^{\aleph_0},$ i.e. the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: So the sequences themselves AS WELL AS as the set of these sequences, $\Sigma$ both have the cardinality of the continuum? $\mid s \mid ^{\aleph _0}$ and $\mid \Sigma \mid ^{\aleph _0}$ ?

Comment: No that doesn't make any sense to me. The sequences in $\Sigma$ are infinite sequences of elements of $D$. As sets they have cardinality $\aleph_0.$

Comment: This is all seems very incidental to me, anyway. We have variables $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\},$ and $\Sigma$ is (conceptually) the collection of all ways to assign elements of $D$ to them. So for instance if $D=\{1,2,3\},$ one such assignment could be represented by $\langle3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3\ldots\rangle$, i.e. $x_1\leftarrow 3,$ $x_2\leftarrow 2$, $x_3\leftarrow 1,$ etc. There are exactly as many of such assignments as there are real numbers, but I'm not sure why that matters.

Comment: So, if for example we had say the wf $(\forall x_1)(A(x_1)\lor (B(x_1)))$ where D = {1,2,3} and A(x) means is even and B(x) means is odd, $\Sigma$ would then be the set of {1,2,3}, {1,3,2}, {3,1,2}, {3,2,1}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1}?

Comment: No... What does a wf have to do with anything? What do evenness and oddness have to do with anything? The only relevant thing in the premise is that $D=\{1,2,3\}$. $\Sigma$ is the set of all infinite sequences of 1's, 2's, and 3's. That's it.

Comment: Now, under a given variable assignment, you could ask whether a given formula is true or false. But the formula you chose doesn't have any free variables.. it is a sentence (which happens to be true in the interpretation you've chosen for A and B), so it doesn't matter what the variable assignment is.

Comment: In this case, for any wf $\mathscr{B}$, $\mathscr{B}\Vdash _K(\forall x_i)\mathscr{B}$, but it is not always the case that $\Vdash _K\mathscr{B}\rightarrow (\forall x_i)\mathscr{B}$. Given $D = \{c,d\}$, let K be a predicate calculus and let $\mathscr{B}$ be $A^1(x_1)$. Interpret $A^1$ as a property that holds only for $c$. Then $A^1$ is satisfied by any sequence $s = (s_1, s_2, ...)$ in which $s_1 = c$, but $(\forall x_1)A^1(x_1)$ is satisfied by no sequence at all... Why is that? I thought it would been satisfied by one sequence at least?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have a structure $M$ and a formula $\varphi$ - possibly with free variables. Since $\varphi$ might have free variables, it's **not** a priori clear that the truth value of $\varphi$ in $M$ is well-defined. For example, is "$x_1$ is even" true in $(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot)$?

For each specific formula $\mathcal{B}$, there's a canonical "type of object" needed to make $\varphi$ "unambiguous" in $M$: namely, a map $$v: FreeVar(\mathcal{B})\rightarrow M$$ assigning a value to each free variable in $M$. However, we could also go for overkill: what sort of object makes **every** formula "unambiguous" in $\mathcal{M}$?

The answer is simply **an assignment of values to *all* variables**. Note that such an $s$ really is overkill: for any specific formula $\mathcal{B}$, $FreeVar(\mathcal{B})$ will be finite but $s$ tells us infinitely many facts.

- In particular, addressing the cardinality question we have $$\vert\Sigma\vert=\vert M\vert^{\aleph_0}$$ (and hence as long as $M$ has more than one element, the corresponding $\Sigma$ will be uncountable!).

---

Now let's look at your final comment above. We need to distinguish **valuations** in the sense above with **instantiations of quantifiers**. The latter **is not relevant here**; we're only looking at the former. For example, when looking at the (very silly) formula $\forall x_1\exists x_3(x_2=x_4)$, only the **second and fourth** values of a sequence $s$ will be "used" when we ask whether $s$ makes that formula true in $M$.

It may help to think about an $s\in\Sigma$ as "acting on" a formula $\mathcal{B}$ to produce a new formula $s(\mathcal{B})$ *with parameters from $M$* - namely, the formula gotten from $\mathcal{}$ by replacing each free variable in $\mathcal{B}$ by the corresponding value given by $s$. Looking at your example, thinking about the valuation $s=(c,d,c,d,...)$ we have

- $s(\forall x_1(x_1=x_2)$ is $\forall x_1(x_1=d)$ since $s(2)=d$.
- $s(\forall x_1(A_1(x_1))$ is just $\forall x_1(A_1(x_1))$ again, since there aren't any free variables for $s$ to do anything to.
- $s(A_1(x_1))=A_1(c)$ since $s(1)=c$.

Note that at no point does $s$ touch the quantifiers of the formula it acts on. In particular, **if $\mathcal{B}$ has no free variables then $s(\mathcal{B})=\mathcal{B}$**.